# How to connect a web-service (PUT-method) from Android via restlet

Tags: android, web-services, rest, restlet

I have a web-service:

```
@Path("/")
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationService implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private DeviceService deviceService;

    @PUT
    @Path( "/register/{device}" )
    @Consumes( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    public String device(@PathParam("device") String device) {
        this.deviceService.saveNewDevice(device);
        return "Succesful!";
    }
}
```

And I have a restlet:

```
public void sendRegistration() {
    ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(REG_URL);
    resource.addSegment(ctx.getString(R.string.config_segment_register));
    ... (?)
}
```

So the current URL will be something like http:// host:port/application/ws/*register*/**pathParam**

How can I do the PUT-call to the web-service? There are methods to add queryParams and I could do addSegment to append the ID to the path, but somehow I need to do the PUT then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to unfortunately not getting to work (maybe because of too little knowledge about/understanding of the API and processing) the suggestion by @Caleryn, I made some similar solution to https://stackoverflow.com/a/735090/1343241

```
@Path("/")
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationService implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private DeviceService deviceService;

    @PUT
    @Path( "/register" )
    @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED )
    @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    public String device(@FormParam("regId") String regId) {
        this.deviceService.saveNewDevice(regId);
        return "Succesful!";
    }
}
```

And in the restlet:

```
Form queryParams = resource.getReference().getQueryAsForm();
queryParams.set("regId", regId);
resource.put(queryParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

almost there try

```
resource.put(representation);
```

where the representation is your plain text document.  Probably a `StringRepresentation` but that is up to you.

Comment: So if the String would be e. g. "myID" and I'd follow your hint by using `new StringRepresentation("myID")` my outcome would look like:
http:// host:post/application/ws/register/myID
?

Comment: Personally I would be puting the entire body of the "device" in the representation to send (everything I wanted to store) to a URL which contained the Id. or potentially just to http:// host:post/application/ws/register and allow the server to assign an id but that depends upon whether your Id can be defined by the server or must be defined by the client.

Comment: Although thinking about it my URL would be either PUT - host/application/devices or PUT - host/application/devices/deviceId.  Using the PUT method itself to define the register action rather than the path.

Comment: The ID is "generated" by the client respectively by Google. It's a GoogleCloudMessaging registration and I need to send the ID to my server.